# Header files not displaying in visual studio with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a C++ project called STFTProject that have the following structure:

```
STFTProject - 
    src - 
        main.cpp
        fft.cpp   
        window.cpp
   
   Headers -        
        config.hpp        
        fft.hpp      
        window.hpp
  
  CMakeLists.txt
```

My CMakeListts.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(STFTProject)

file(GLOB SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "Headers/*.hpp")

include_directories(Headers)

add_executable(STFTProject ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

After building with CMake in the cmd with the command "cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"

to generate a visual studio solution I can only see the source files in the IDE:

[image: Visual Studio Solution]

There is no header files filter with all the header files that I have but the source files do recognize those headers files.

I do want to be able to see the header files and edit them as I continue with the project, how can I do this ?

Comment: This should work although I don't normally use globbing.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio **Code**.  When using Visual Studio, you need to run the `devenv` (Development environment) and run your command line codes in there (like CMake).

Comment: Visual Studio uses *projects* and *solutions*.  Visual Studio has the functionality to generate a CMake file.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my CMakeLists.txt file  to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(STFTProject)

include_directories(include)

file(GLOB SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "Headers/*.h")

add_executable(STFTProject ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

Ant it worked, not sure why tough.

Comment: Because `GLOB` does not see directory changes until you remove CMakeCache.txt or modify CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: For globbing you have to get CMake to generate before you can see the changes. If CMake does not generate it will not show up in VS.